# Chrome ブラウザからAndroidアプリを開きたい

Tags: android

Androidのクロームブラウザからアプリを開きたいのですが、できません。

Androidアプリで下記インテントフィルタを指定し、

intent-filter

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="signincallback"
                    android:path="/"
                    android:scheme="myapp" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Chromeで下記urlにリダイレクトしましたがアプリが起動しません。
どのように指定すればいいのでしょうか。

URL

```
intent://signincallback/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.example;S.exist=true;end
```

Comment: Chrome独自のIntentスキーマについての説明は [Android Intents with Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) にあります。

Comment: コメントありがとう御座います。
そのページを参考にしましたができませんでした。もしかして、リダイレクトではできないということでしょうか。

Comment: はい、上記ページにリダイレクトの場合、ユーザジェスチャを伴わない場合には外部アプリを起動しないと説明があります（最下部）。

Comment: ではユーザにクリックしてもらう方法以外に無いということでしょうか。それとも他に自動的に遷移させる方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: 今Webページとリンクを用意しましたが、リンクをクリックしてもアプリに戻ることができませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

少し前までの Android Studio のバグで、マニフェスト内においてパーミッションやインテントフィルタ関係の文字列へのコード補完をする際に、小文字の部分が大文字になってしまうというのがありました。

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=157123

```
<category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.BROWSABLE" />
```

この部分は以下のようになってないと動いてくれなかったと思います。

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```